# How to raise the error when button not existing in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to raise the error when some button doesn't exist in the page.

Like 'next button' is no longer existing at the last post, I want to raise some error

can you teach me some hints to carry this out?

Thank you!

Comment: It would be good to see what you've tried so far and to get an idea of the page(s) you're working with. However, a try/except block would probably do the trick, just make sure you specify the exception type that the missing button raises.

Answer (score 0):

First wait for the page to load by checking whether a certain element on the page is visible. Then check for invisibility of the button

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, waitTime); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions. invisibilityOfElementWithText(by, someText));
```